# Why is XCUITest Failing on Xcode running iOS 11.0.1

Tags: ios, xcode9, swift4, xcuitest

My UITests were running fine till xcode 8.3 (iOS 10). After updating xcode and upgrading to swift 4 Test Fails with following error

> crashed in external symbol
>
> iOSSimulator: Unable to connect to
>   "com.apple.instruments.deviceservice.lockdown" (Error
>   Domain=DTiPhoneSimulatorErrorDomain Code=-1 "DTServiceHubClient failed
>   to bless service hub for simulator iPhone 7 Plus
>   (F8CB0FF4-5A28-4149-841F-70162DFB6228)"
>   UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=DTServiceHubClient failed to bless
>   service hub for simulator iPhone 7 Plus
>   (F8CB0FF4-5A28-4149-841F-70162DFB6228),
>   NSUnderlyingError=0x7f92283856d0 {Error
>   Domain=DTiPhoneSimulatorErrorDomain Code=-1
>   "blessSimulatorServiceHub:error: failed but didn't provide an error"
>   UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=blessSimulatorServiceHub:error:
>   failed but didn't provide an error}}})

Simulator boots, app installs and then simulator crashes right there.

Down grading the swift file to 3.2 and making necessary downgrade changes and running on xcode 8.3 Tests runs like charm.

I tested it on different Mac. Same error occurs.

I can't really guess whats messing up on xcode 9

Answer (score 3):

This seems to be Xcode Bug. After updating to Xcode 9.1 this error vanished.